# How can I follow a post?

Tags: support, feature-request

there is a question that I -1'd because of not putting enough info ,if I want to follow that post to be notified of new answer,comments,or edits.

How can I follow that question/post?

if that feature isn't available then I request to add it to the site(s)

Comment: There's a relevant discussion (probably several) on Meta.SO about this: [Mark questions to receive notifications and updates?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/mark-questions-to-receive-notifications-and-updates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you "Favorite" a question you will get notifications of updates.

That's the "star" icon under the voting buttons.

See also: [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Answer (score 0):

There is a  "question feed", which is a RSS (?) for a question. You can find the feeds url in the bottom right corner of every question page. Or just search on the question for "question feed".

Firefox has the "live bookmarks" feature to monitor RSS feeds, alternatively you could use [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/) to reader RSS/Atom feeds in the could.

Comment: that's not what I wanted ,I mean that it informs me like it informs the author of new updates in the question.